# rendering a dynamic web page and my javascript files cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am linking to a dynamic web page in my navbar like this

```
<li class="<%= title == 'Cryptofolio' ? 'navbar-item active' : 'navbar-item' %>">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/cryptofolio/<%- locals.user.username %> ">Cryptofolio</a>
</li>
```

I have a route setup for this

```js
  app.get('/cryptofolio/:username',isAuthenticated, function(req,res) {
      res.render('cryptofolio', {title:'Cryptofolio'});
  })
```

The page redirects fine, but none of my javascript files are being loaded, checking the console in chrome gives me theses errors

```
GET http://localhost:3000/cryptofolio/javascripts/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/cryptofolio/javascripts/favorites.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I have a components file that has all of my scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.3/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.3/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="javascripts/index.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/favorites.js"></script>
```

I then include said script in my HTML file

```
<% include components/scripts.ejs %>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the include or routing ? I cannot figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help
You need to add the following code to app.js (which is applications main entry point. defines in the package.json start script)

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/javascripts'));`
this will set 'localhost:PORT' folder as ./javascripts.

Then in the ejs, just import the script as `<script src="index.js"></script>`

Comment: Hey, Didn't add it to my example but i'm using this for my paths `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  
`  doing it your way gave me a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ` error

Comment: This worked for me. But why did you add public here? May I know? And the error you got, is it received after you put this line of code?

Comment: Try to remove path.join method and instead of public use the name of the folder you have placed your javascripts. And also when you import scripts inside ejs, use only the script name. As an example <script src="index.js"></script>

Comment: __dirname will gives you the current directory of the working file. Since app.js is inside the root folder, You just need to give the directory name of which you have placed the javascripts.  If your javascripts placed inside the public folder, add / before the public string ('/public')

Comment: Hey, that fixed the issue. Thank you !

Comment: It's a pleasure.Happy coding mate